# XAML, MVVM and waiting for things to happen

Tags: wpf, xaml

Alright, so I'm creating a WPF application using the MVVM design principles anad C# as the language.

I have a singleton for my database (called 'Database'), which just loads some data from an XML file.

I also have a view model (ScenesViewModel) which needs to get this data once it's loaded.

At the moment, the Database calls its Load method in MainWindow.Xaml.cs (just below InitializeComponent) and the constructor of ScenesViewModel gets the data from the Database singleton.

The problem is that the constructor for ScenesViewModel happens before the singleton does its loading.

I suppose I could have a reference to ScenesViewModel in the Database singleton, but that seems like bad practise to me. Is there a better way?

I am, as you may be able to tell, no expert in this field.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: Create the singleton before you create the view model and inject the view model with the singleton?

Answer (score 0):

Load data from Database async and use await keyword waiting until data loads from database. Go to reference: 
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx